# Mouse Over CSS Issue (CSS applying opacity afterwards)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How come when someone mouses over the Google Icon, Instagram and Facebook Icon they appear faded afterwards.

This also is happening in mobile responsive menu where text fades and doesn't return to its original color state.

Website is hopkinslawokc.com

Comment: Sometimes when you hit an issue like this it is far easier to recreate the nav by itself...like in a code pen or some such place, that way it is easier to narrow down the issue.  From what I can see...once you hover over the LI (list item) the opacity on that LI is set to .35.  Then when you hover over it again the LI is changed to an opacity of 1.  These are inline styles being set on the LI html element itself.  Certainly that is some Javascript making this change but it I don't know which javascript file is doing it.

Comment: Please include code in the question itself.... just enough to replicate the issue: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have not opacity set, But if you hover over the icons than got he a opacity. If you give the li > id give a opacity. so li id="menu-item-40 opacity: 0.35;

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Social Hover
 jQuery(".social-icon").hover(function(){
  jQuery(this).animate({ opacity: 0.35 }, 150);
 }, function(){
  jQuery(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 150);
 });

/* this bit of code was found in
http://hopkinslawokc.com/wp-content/themes/goodspace-v1-11/javascript/gdl-scripts.js
*/
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 36px;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
  <li class="social-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="social-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="social-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It is working just as expected except what the first answer said...if you want it to appear faded from the get go then you need to add it in the css.

Comment: I want it to return to its original color state as set in the CSS code.

Comment: So when page loads you want opacity to be 1 and then when someone hovers on it you want it to fade setting opacity to .35.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes. then after they hover off I want it to return to 1

Comment: Ok...now check the example.  You will need to up data that javascript function for social hover.  Since opacity defaults to 1 it is not needed in the CSS. I have to tell you though..fading on hover is not really a good interaction since faded items give the impression of disabled.

Comment: Maybe im not making sense. I want them to be the full color at first, and then when they mouse over fade them to 50% opacity. When the mouse leaves I want it to return to the original color.

Comment: Greg,  I have broken the code out and shown you what the issue is.  The question has been answered.  You are now becoming a client.  Take what I have shown you...(its all in your code and I have shown you where) and make it do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

this is the css only solution.

```css
ul {
      list-style: none;
      font-size: 36px;
    }

ul li {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 20px;
      opacity:.35;
      transition: all 150ms linear;
    }
ul li:hover{opacity:1;}
.fa-facebook{color:blue;}
.fa-twitter{color:#2b2626;}
.fa-google{color:#ff0000;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
  <li class="social-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="social-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="social-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```